# Changing text color in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, text, colors

I'm trying to change the text color in Eclipse (version 3.7).

From what I've read about this it seems I should be able to change the java editor text by going to window > preferences > general > appearance > colors and fonts, selecting java > java editor text and clicking "edit".

When I do this and choose a different color, however, it simply reverts to black whenever I click "ok". I can change the font, size and other attributes, just not color. I've tried changing the "set to default: text font" to "overrides default:text font", right clicking the text I want changed and selecting preferences from there, changing the basic > text font (same problem).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring
```

Answer (score 3):

For OSX Users:

```
 Eclipse/ADT > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit different way, but the best for me (because there are a lot nice and ready font-color themes) is to import font settings with preferences- that can be done through xml settings : http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftimpandexp.htm
In my case I just imported whole Visual Studio based font colors scheme (xml files can be found in internet)- that took me 10 seconds + eclipse restart.